# What happens to the ETH if the contract is canceled?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I sent ETH to a company during their ICO. The contract, on Etherscan shows, Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction] and the contract was canceled. My question is what happens to the ETH?? My wallet still shows that the ETH was deducted but no log of ever getting it back. What happened to it? Can I get it back?

Also tried to create a tag here "canceled-contract", but I'm too new yet.

Comment: If the transaction was reverted (sounds like it was, but share the transaction hash so someone can confirm), then the ether never went anywhere. If you're using some sort of exchange, then they still have the ether. If you used your own account, then you still have the ether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was an error during contract execution (which Etherscan seems to tell you there was), then the transaction will revert and the Ether will never have left your wallet. What wallet are you using?

Comment: That makes sense and is what I thought. However, I am unable to find an audit trail that the ETH never left my wallet actually happened. The balance still reflects the debit not the credit. For this discussion, I was using Jaxx